# Caliburn + Spring.NET - Configure Bootstraper

Tags: dependency-injection, bootstrapping, spring.net, caliburn

I would like use Spring.NET for IoC , DI, AOP and Caliburn as MVVVM framework.

But I can’t find any sample how configure bootstraper for Spring.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caliburn supports DI containers through a common `IServiceLocator` interface, for which a spring.net implementation is provided. See the Caliburn page on [project setup](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Project%20Setup).